# BASH: check if an array element is empty, But when there is a element '0'

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, is-empty

I'm learning arrays in bash, and I'm learning to check if an element is empty when there is a element contain integer '0'
For example,

```
declare -A Rank
Rank[0]=0
if [ ${#Rank[0]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Empty"
else
    echo "Not empty"
fi
```

The result is "Not empty" for this case, so I thought this is how we check an element of associative array is empty. However, when I'm building my program:

```
declare -A Rank
declare -A arrayPoint

num=4
    for (( i=0; i<num; i++)); do 
        j=0
        while [ $j -ne $num ]; do
            if [ ${#Rank[j]} -eq 0 ]; then # only need to look at this part
                Rank[$j]=$i 
                break;
            elif [ "${ArrayPoint[$i]}" -g ]; then
                k=$(($num-1))
                while [ $k -ne 0 ]; do
                    Rank[$k]=${Rank[$(($k-1))]}
                    ((--k))
                done
                Rank[$j]=$i
                break;
            fi
        ((j++))
        done
    done
```

`Rank` is an empty array, so when `i=0`, it should store the integer 0 in this line: `Rank[$j]=$i`, which means on the next iteration when `j=1`, it should skip the first `if` condition and head to the `elif`, but when I debug, it does not skip the first `if`. Here are the debug codes.

```
+ declare -A arrayPoint
+ declare -A Rank
+ num=4
+ (( i=0 ))
+ (( i<num ))
+ j=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 4 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ Rank[$j]=0
+ break
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<num ))
+ j=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 4 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ Rank[$j]=1
+ break
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<num ))
+ j=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 4 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ Rank[$j]=2
+ break
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<num ))
+ j=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 4 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ Rank[$j]=3
+ break
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<num ))
```

I think the problem should be in `if [ ${#Rank[j]} -eq 0 ];` since it's has never go down further than the first `if` statement. Please let me know if I missed something. Thank you.

Comment: Use `${#Rank[$j]}`. Keys of an associative array are strings, using bare`j` means the string `"j"`.

Comment: It looks like you're using numeric indexes with these arrays, in which case why make them associative rather than plain arrays? Also, what is `[ "${ArrayPoint[$i]}" -g ]` supposed to do?